# How to check if given parameter is int or char in C#?

Tags: c#, types, char, int, comparison

I have a simple method which expects an integer value as a parameter:

```
 public const string IndexIsNotANumber = "The given index is not a number!";

    public Fibonacci() { }

    public int GetNumberByIndex(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(index);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new FormatException(IndexIsNotANumber);
        }
    }
```

And an appropriate test:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void PassChar()
    {
        //arrange
        char index = 'A';
        Fibonacci fibonacci = new Fibonacci();

        //act
        try
        {
            int b = fibonacci.GetNumberByIndex(index);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            // assert  
            StringAssert.Contains(e.Message, Fibonacci.IndexIsNotANumber);
            return;
        }
        Assert.Fail("No exception was thrown.");
    }
```

**The problem is that the test always fails with "No exception was thrown" error**
So how can I be ensured that the given parameter isn't a char ?

Comment: It is convert.toInt32 is converting ascii value of 'A'

Comment: @shyam I know. It's just one of the lot of approaches I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetType() function with if condition.

```
if(index.GetType()==typeof(int))
{
 //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use- **int.TryParse(string s,Out)**

This method converts the string to integer out variable and returns true if successfully parsed, 
otherwise false. If string s is null, then the out variable has 0 rather than throw ArgumentNullException

Comment: Please, give a little example

Comment: string input = "yourInput";
int result; 

if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
{
   //your code if it is integer 
}

Comment: How I supposed to use it? I have integer as parameter, not a string.

Comment: OMG! It works! I just replaced your result to index and then it started to work! Thank you!

Comment: No sorry, it doesn't work. This code `string input = "inputData";
            if (!int.TryParse(input, out index))
            { 
                throw new FormatException(IndexIsNotANumber);
            }` always throws the error even if the parameter is int

Answer (score 0):

The code will never throw an exception due to the type of *index* is int already:
 Convert.ToInt32(index);
Convert.ToInt32(char) used to get ASCII code of char, so you should use int.Parse instead.

Try this:

```
public int GetNumberByIndex(char index)
{
    try
    {
        //Convert.ToInt32(index);
        int.Parse(index.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new FormatException(IndexIsNotANumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will successfully convert any ascii char to int.

Answer (score 0):

So I have resolved the problem by overloading the method:

```
  public int GetNumberByIndex(int index)
  {
      /**/
  }
  public int GetNumberByIndex(char index)
  {
      throw new FormatException(IndexIsNotANumber);
  }
```

**It's not a good example**, but as I can see no one knows a better way.